# Wrong version of pg_dump on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, postgresql-9.3

I originally installed postgres 9.2 on Ubuntu and later upgraded to 9.3 according to the instructions here: http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/ (using the postgres apt repository).

However, pg_dump, which is an alias for /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper, did not get upgraded.

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.4; pg_dump version: 9.2.8
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

How do I upgrade this? I have tried to figure out which packages require update, but I'm not really even sure that that's the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turns out that installing the 9.3 client does not auto uninstall the 9.2 client, and if they're both on the machine like this, then that's what you get. The answer is to remove the postgresql-client-9.2 (or whatever the appropriate old version is in your case).

Comment: For upgrading client: Add the postgresql repo like this http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Then run `apt-cache search postgresql-client-9`and pick whichever suits your needs.

Comment: You might want to also know that upgrading `pg_dump` first requires `apt-get --only-upgrade install postgresql-client` after which you have to uninstall the previous client version:  `apt-get --purge remove postgresql-client-9.2`, for example.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to have **several** versions of postgresql client same time you may use

```
pg_dump --cluster 9.2/main [other pg_dump options]
```

for old cluster and

```
pg_dump --cluster 9.3/main [other pg_dump options]
```

for new

View accepted answer on askubuntu for details: https://askubuntu.com/a/647341/1044581

Answer (score 8):

I managed to fix my issues by uninstalling the postgresql client

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-client-common
```

And then re-installing

```
  sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-11
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-11 ... is there some way to update the postgres index

Comment: I believe that you might need to update your apt indexes, as I don't know if postgresql package is part of the default index set. try googling 'install postgresql 11 on ubuntu' for more details.

Comment: Here is an explicit link to installing postgresql 11 client tools: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-postgresql-11-on-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: You might need to add a repository for the latest prostgres versions: https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

Answer (score 6):

you may want to check output of the command

> dpkg -l | grep postgres

to see which versions are  installed and active
pg_dump is usually part of postgresql-client-common package.

(And edit your question, It is not clear how did you upgrade from version 9.3 to 9.3 ... )

Answer (score 4):

**tl:dr;** no need to uninstall old clusters. Instead, put the following in `~/.postgresqlrc`

`<version> <clustername> <defaultdb>`,

e.g., `9.6 main *`

---

It's not necessary to uninstall old clusters. I looked in `/usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper`, which has these lines:

```
# for psql we always want the latest version, as this is backwards 
compatible
# to every major version that that we support
if ($cmdname eq 'pg_wrapper') {
    error "pg_wrapper should not be called directly, but through a symlink";
} elsif ($cmdname =~ /^(psql|pg_archivecleanup|pg_isready)$/) {
    $cmd = get_program_path ($cmdname, get_newest_version);
} else {
    $cmd = get_program_path ($cmdname, $version);
}
```

In other words, commands like `psql` will always be run with the latest installed version installed on your machine, but commands like `pg_dump` will not.

At the top of `pg_wrapper` is a hint:

```
# Call a PostgreSQL client program with the version, cluster and default
# database specified in ~/.postgresqlrc or
# /etc/postgresql-common/user_clusters.
```

`man postgresqlrc` tells us that `~/.postgresqlrc` should be formatted thusly:

`<version> <cluster name> <default database`

`pg_lsclusters` gave me the following output:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory               Log file
9.5 main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log
9.6 main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.6-main.log
```

Which meant that my `~/.postgresqlrc` should look like this:

`9.6 main *`

Which gives me the desired version when I run `pg_dump -V`.

Comment: Very useful debug info. I noticed after installing the main binary with `apt install postgresql-15` (instead of `postgresql-client-15`), the `pg_lsclusters` entry highlighted in green instead of red. It didn't change the default version for `pg_dump`, but put me on track to understanding what was happening.

Comment: Swapping the port numbers in the Postgresql config changed the default version I got when running `pg_dump`. Whichever version used port `5432` is the one that becomes the default. (As in, `sudo vi /etc/postgresql/15/main/postgresql.conf`, update the port entry, and do the same for whatever other version is installed).

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing same issue. First, I removed old pgdump versions. Mostly it is part of postres-client. So, remove them by using

> apt-get remove postgresql-client-common

Install the version as per your requirement, by executing following commands. I am using ubuntu 16.04. Replace, "xenial" by your ubuntu version, in the first command.
Command to check ubuntu version-
`cat /etc/os-release`

> $ echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
>     $ wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
>     $ sudo apt-get update
>     $ apt-cache search postgresql | grep postgresql-client
>     $ apt-get install postgresql-client-9.5

Answer (score 1):

To use a specific version of `pg_dump`

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/13/bin/pg_dump
```

---

You can also run `find / -name 'pg_dump'` to find available paths

[image: result of command]

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta
find / -name 'pg_dump'
Resultado
/usr/bin/pg_dump
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_dump

su - postgres
Prueba
/usr/bin/pg_dump database > database52.sql
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/pg_dump database > database52.sql